# Cross Domain GET request, hitting server but not getting response

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, get-request

I am trying to make a cross domain GET request for an inline subscription widget (you type in your email address in a text box, and it will subscribe you to a mailing list without redirecting you to a different page). The URL in the code below is supposed to send an email in addition to sending back information in the form of json (the information will tell you whether the call was successful, whether the email entered is in correct form, the email is already on the list etc). The code below generates an email when executed (congrats, you are on the list), but I am unable to receive information back (so I can't tell the user to enter their email in the correct format, their email is already on the list etc). I'm not really sure what to do -- in order for this to work, I cannot pass anything in addition to the data in the call (email, list_number, and key). From what I have been testing, using the jsonp dataType concatenates a "callback" function to the url -- in my case, adding this breaks everything.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$("subscribe-form").submit(function(e) {

    var email = $("input-EMAIL").val();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonp: false,
        url: "https://inserturlhere/maillistsubscriber/listSubscribe",
        data: { email: email, list_number: '#######', key: '#encoded#'},
        success:function(){
            alert("An Error Occurred. Try Again :( ");
    },
        error: function () {
            $('div.invitation').html("<br><p>Thank you for submitting! Check your inbox every Friday for the newsletter!</p>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(750);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: you might want to make that huge paragraph shorter if u need any answers here :)

Comment: I assume you just pasted the code wrong, but your success and error handlers are opposite.

Comment: have you monitored the actual network traffic to see what the request/response is?

Comment: the way the response works is {error: false} for success, {error: InvalidEmail} etc. it is weird yes, but that is how the backend is set up

Comment: if your server returns a 200 response with {error: false} in the data, jquery is going to execute the success block, not the error

Answer (score 1):

if this is through different domains simple ajax will not work.

you can try

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: BotMind.messagingUrl+"send",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            type: "GET",

            complete: function(){
                //alert('complete message');
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                $('div.invitation').html("<br><p>Thank you for submitting! Check your inbox every Friday for the newsletter!</p>")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(750);

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An Error Occurred. Try Again :( ");
    },
            statusCode: {
                404: function() {
                    //alert("page not found");
                },
                200: function() {
                    //alert("page ok");
                }
            }
        });
```

this will surely work